Front audio jack not working on Ubuntu 24.04
I had sound on my headphone via front audio jack of my PC but now after I have fresh installed Ubuntu 24.04 it doesn't work! I searched all the similar topics about using pavcontrol, alsamixer, headjackretask and ... but none of them works. The weird thing is that I can hear the sound of beep sounds in terminal when i press tab key but when i play some music it doesn't!

I moved back to 22.04 and by just installing pavucontrol it solved my problem but it's weird why it couldn't work in 24.04!
